# Why Is My Set Up Cutting Off My Constraints To Margins?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, autolayout, constraints, horizontalscrollview

I'm working from a storyboard connected to a `UIViewController` as such:

[image]

UPDATE:

The Problem Seems to be that my constraints do not pin to margins. Here are my constraints pinning to the bottom.

[image]

Here is how that translates to different devices.
[image]
[image]

I have messed with the various size settings shown in the second to last picture. I will try a more systematic approach to changing these if  someone isn’t able to very easily detect why this is occurring. It seems unrelated to the Page Control and more related to page sizing

[Project Github HERE](https://github.com/swimnbird/BeliefTherapyApp)

Note again, this is the exact same problem I get even when creating the view controller in the method used at:
[HERE](http://seemuapps.com/page-view-controller-tutorial-with-page-dots)
I chose the code used as opposed to the code at the link only because I had already coded this and they were identical in issue, I have become aware sense then that this is a more complicated way to accomplish this though.
The issue is recreated perfectly with a simple constraint to the bottom.

Comment: But the tutorial code is not where the bug is. Is it? And getting rid of everything that can be gotten rid of is exactly how you isolate problems and solve them.

Comment: If the tutorial code has the same issue, tell me where and how to elicit it. That is what I asked before.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion. This was not similar to the tutorial code I realized so I'm glad the convo got me to check this... the code up now is what you were asking. Thank you for your patience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code / storyboard, but I think the problem you're complaining about is here:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds // *
        } else if view is UIPageControl {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the line that I've commented.

(If you also change the color in the last line to `.red`, just as an experiment, you will be able to see the page control, and you'll see that the text view is behaving consistently on different sizes of device.)

Comment: Okay wow, first, thankyou greatly, I really appreciate you taking time to open it up and detect the problem. Now I'm wondering what other of the many issues you recognized were, and would you be willing to make your version of this so I could view it? (If not I understand). Your instruction on how you would have approached it came off with the subtext of "this is super simple, just do this" but as a beginner it wasn't as obvious and I felt limited by the tutorials made for this as most were from swift 3 and caused similar issues somehow, I do want to learn the best way, is this in your book?

Comment: Main things I noticed were: there should be no segues in the storyboard from the page view controller to anything; and, loading up an array of view controllers as the children of the page view controller is wrong — the whole idea is that you create the next/previous view controller when you are asked for it.